# Is it posible to have destructor logic for knockout custom bindings?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a custom binding which initializes an object which needs to be destructed after the bound element is removed.

The only option I can think of is detecting when the element is gone and then destroying the object but I still haven't found a way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knockout has a [custom disposal](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-disposal.html) callback you can call. The example from [their page](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-disposal.html).

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myWidget = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()),
            $el = $(element);
 
        $el.myWidget(options);
 
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
            // This will be called when the element is removed by Knockout or
            // if some other part of your code calls ko.removeNode(element)
            $el.myWidget("destroy");
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved` in your `init` ?

> The disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved option ensures that this computed
>   observable will be destroyed if Knockout removes our element, like in
>   a templating scenario.

**Code Sample:**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.isolatedOptions = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var args = arguments;
        ko.computed({
            read:  function() {
               ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
               ko.bindingHandlers.options.update.apply(this, args);
            },
            owner: this,
            disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved: element
        });
    }
};
```

Source: [Knockout.js Performance Gotcha #3 - All Bindings Fire Together.](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/06/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha-3-all-bindings.html)